# How to spot a memory leak problem within my code

Tags: c, memory-leaks, openssl

I have memory leak issue, I suspect the problem could be in the "base64_decode()" function below. Also, please read comments spread across the code.

```
uint8_t *unbase64_ct = NULL;
uint8_t *unbase64_sig = NULL;

int i = 0;

 // ptr is just a buffer of fixed size containing encoded data 
 //separated with delim (i.e. "&" sign). The ptr may contain 
 //base64(ct)&base64(sig)& where base64(ct) is encoded ciphertext and 
 //base64(sig) is encoded signature of public key cryptography

char *next = NULL;
char *tokens = strtok_r(ptr, delim, &next);

do
{
    if(i == 0)
    {
        int ln = strlen(tokens);
        unbase64_ct = base64_decode((uint8_t*)tokens, (uint32_t*)&ln);
        i++;
        continue;
    }

    if(i == 1)
    {
        int ln = strlen(tokens);
        unbase64_sig = base64_decode((uint8_t*)tokens, (uint32_t*)&ln);
        i++;
        continue;
    }
}
while((tokens = strtok_r(NULL, delim, &next)) != NULL);

// I believe this function leaves leftovers.
uint8_t *base64_decode(uint8_t *bbuf, uint32_t *len)
{
     uint8_t *ret;
     uint32_t bin_len;

     bin_len = (((strlen((char*)bbuf) + 3)/4) * 3);
     ret = (uint8_t*)malloc(bin_len);

    *len = EVP_DecodeBlock(ret, bbuf, strlen((char*)bbuf));
     // Following good code practice, ret must be freed within the 
     //code block... 
     //However, how do i pass random number of bytes in the 
     //different way without using malloc?
     return ret;
}

// I release here unbase64_ct and unbase64_sig as the output is 
// dynamically allocated.

free(tokens);
free(unbase64_ct);
free(unbase64_sig);
```

It works totally fine, however after running this whole code multiple times like 1000, it stops on the random value in range of 100 - 1000. How can I rewrite base64_decode function without dynamic memory allocation, or spot a memory leak problem which I cannot see?

Comment: Each time you call `base64_decode` you also allocate memory. That means for each call to `base64_decode` you need to `free` the pointer it returns.

Comment: You also should *not* pass pointer to `free` that weren't created by `malloc`, like e.g. `tokens`.

Comment: I totally agree that for each call base64_decode, I should free the pointer it returns.  free(unbase64_ct);   I believe these two line does that no?
              free(unbase64_sig);

Comment: `int ln` --> `uint32_t ln`  and drop the cast `(uint32_t*)`

Comment: You say best practice would be to free it in the function.  This isn't necessarily true in C.  Often times, you return pointers that were allocated that the client has to release.  How are you doing you iterations?  Are you releasing the returned pointer in each one, or once at the end?

Comment: It's really hard to say what you really do because the code is all mixed up. Please try to create a [mcve] to show us.

Comment: "for" loop, inside a function containing this code.

Comment: I found the issue, basically It was unmanaged length of unbase64_sig outside of the code.

Comment: Anyways guys, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

Each call to `base64_decode` allocates a new buffer, so `unbase64_ct` and `unbase64_sig` are malloc'd many times but they are only freed once.

Comment: That's very interesting answer, what would you suggest instead?

Comment: You have to somehow keep track of the buffer locations until after they are used so that you can free them later. I can't offer much more detail as that would simply be completing your assignment for you.